# How can I get wp_get_nav_menu_items to group child items with parents?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Referring to the function wp_get_nav_menu_items() https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_nav_menu_items/#

It returns an object with all menu items of a given menu, including submenu items, in the order they are arranged on the dashboard. It does not group submenu items with their parent items, which can make creating your own menu a little difficult. Is there a way to arrange the object so that child items are grouped inside an array in their parent item?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
        // wordpress does not group child menu items with parent menu items
        $menuLocations = get_nav_menu_locations();
        $navbar_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menuLocations['Navbar']);
        $child_items = [];

        // pull all child menu items into separate object
        foreach ($navbar_items as $key => $item) {
            if ($item->menu_item_parent) {
                array_push($child_items, $item);
                unset($navbar_items[$key]);
            }
        }

        // push child items into their parent item in the original object
        foreach ($navbar_items as $item) {
            foreach ($child_items as $key => $child) {
                if ($child->menu_item_parent == $item->post_name) {
                    if (!$item->child_items) {
                        $item->child_items = [];
                    }

                    array_push($item->child_items, $child);
                    unset($child_items[$key]);
                }
            }
        }

        // return navbar object where child items are grouped with parents
        return $navbar_items;
```

Comment: Comment below is corrent, because 'menu_item_parent' is intiger in string type and 'object_type' is intiger in string too.

Comment: I had to change `if ($child->menu_item_parent == $item->post_name) {` to    `if ($child->menu_item_parent == $item->ID) {` under the 'push child items into their parent item...' section to get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

To solve your problem, you can change these two lines:

```
foreach ($item as $key => $child)
        if ($child->menu_item_parent == $item->post_name) {
```

With:

```
 foreach ($child_items as $key => $child)
       if ($child->menu_item_parent == $item->object_id) {
```